# need help with creating my first gazebo plugin

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-fuerte, gazebo-plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

my intention is to control and move a simple robot within the gazebo simulation. i already created the robot model with a urdf file and now i want to move it around.
as i understand, the best way to do that, is to create a plugin.
i tried to follow step by step the instructions on :

http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/GazeboPluginIntro

but when i type "rosmake" I get an error :

**/home/daniel/ros_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/src/simple_world_plugin.cpp:1:20: fatal error: gazebo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.**

I tried to update ROS by typing  **"sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full"**   but still, the problem remains.

I am using ROS Fuerte with Ubuntu 12.04.

Is anyone can suggest a better tutorial, or a way to overcome this problem?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36635/need-help-with-creating-my-first-gazebo-plugin/) by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 192 on 2012-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-06-17**:
have you set your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH correctly ?
if not try rospack profile then export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, that should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem and found that if you include "common/Plugin.hh" instead of "gazebo.h" it will work. My only explanation for why is that the tutorial is a "work in progress."

---

Originally posted by [rctaylor](https://answers.ros.org/users/2644/rctaylor/) with karma: 36 on 2012-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The intro tutorial was updated. Maybe you can try it again? I managed to complete the hello.world example.

---

Originally posted by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) with karma: 201 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1